# Faking a canvas -- Can this work?

Tags: javascript, canvas, prototype

I am trying to "fake" a canvas, with this intension to hand this fake canvas over to a, possibly arbitrary, framework to post-process all the line-, curve- and moveTo's.

To manage this I tried this code, which actually worked, but I would like to know how much luck I had with this lucky shot.

```
(function(){
    function DebugCanvas(){
        this._dom = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
        addPropertiesToObject.call( this, this._dom );
        this._fakeContext = null;
    }

    Object.defineProperties( DebugCanvas.prototype, 
    {   
        'constructor' : {
            'value' : DebugCanvas,
            'enumerable' : true
        },

        'getContext' : {
            'value' : function( which ){
                var ctx;
                if( which == '2d' ){
                    if( this._fakeContext == null ){
                        this._fakeContext = new FakeContext( this._dom );
                    }
                    ctx = this._fakeContext;
                } else {
                    ctx = this._dom.getContext( which );
                }
                return ctx;
            },
            'enumerable' : true
        }
    }
);

function FakeContext( debugCanvas ){
    this._debugCanvas = debugCanvas;
    this._realContext = debugCanvas._dom.getContext( '2d' );
    addPropertiesToObject.call( this, this._realContext );
}

Object.defineProperties( FakeContext.prototype, {
    'toString' : {
        'value' : function(){
            return '[Object FakeContext]';
        },
        'enumerable' : true
    },

    'canvas' : {
        'get' : function(){
            return this._debugCanvas;
        },
        'set' : function( c ){ return },
        'enumerable' : true
    }
});

function addPropertiesToObject( from ){
    var description, obj;

    for( var prop in from ){
        obj = from;
        do {
            if( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) && 
                !this.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ){

                try{
                    description = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( obj, prop );
                    Object.defineProperty( this.constructor.prototype, prop, description );
                } catch( err ){
                    this[ prop ] = from[ prop ]; 
                }
                break;
            }
        } while( obj = Object.getPrototypeOf( obj ) );
    }
};
})()
```

the basic idea is to copy all of the canvas', canvas.prototypes' (all the chain upwards), contexts' and context.prototypes' properties to the fake objects' prototype, as far as they are not already present there.

Comment: whats the problem with using a real canvas?

Comment: »post-process all draw-commands«, that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, you can freely construct a replacement object with all the same properties/methods as the original and use it in place of the original.  Method calls or property access will be the same either way and calling code will generally not know the difference.  This can be a very useful thing to do at times in javascript.

The more complicated part of a replacement like this is emulating the actual behavior of all the methods and properties such that the code you pass it to works as you want.  But, if you can successfully do that, it should work fine.  There's no luck involved - this is supposed to work as long as your emulation of the methods/properties is right.

Comment: it actually works for the test environment I have set up. I am just unsure about which behavior I cannot emulate...

Comment: @philipp - that's the hard part, especially for a rich object like you've chosen.  It will depend entirely upon what the code that you're passing the fake object to tries to do with it and what results it expects.

Comment: override all the callbacks of the context, so that I can hand in the coordinates. On of the intentions is described here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/scrolling-box2d-debugdraw Next by, being able to hand in there can be quite nice for other frameworks like processing